# How to get Vite to serve assets through Homestead?

Tags: javascript, vite, homestead

I have a fresh Laravel install (minus adding Vue.js) which is served via Homestead. When I visit my page in the browser, I see that the JavaScript is failing to load because of the follow error: `https://my-homestead-url.test:5174/js/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

My homestead.yaml looks like this:

```yaml
    ip: "192.168.56.12"
    memory: 2048
    cpus: 2
    provider: virtualbox
    
    authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    ssl: true
    keys:
        - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    
    folders:
        - map: ~/code
          to: /home/vagrant/code
    
    sites:
        - map: my-homestead-url.test
          to: /home/vagrant/code/my-homestead-project/public
          php: "8.0"
    
    databases:
        - my_homestead_url_db
    
    features:
        - mysql: true
        - mariadb: false
        - ohmyzsh: false
        - webdriver: false
    
    ports:
     - send: 5173
       to: 5173
```

and my vite.config.js file looks like this:

```js
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
    import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
    import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
    import fs from 'node:fs';
    import path from 'node:path';
    
    export default defineConfig({
        server: {
            host: 'my-homestead-url.test',
            https: false,
            hmr: {
                host: 'my-homestead-url.test',
            },
        },
        plugins: [
            vue({
                template: {
                    transformAssetUrls: {
                        base: null,
                        includeAbsolute: false,
                    }
                }
            }),
            laravel({
                input: [
                    // 'resources/css/app.css',
                    'resources/js/app.js',
                ],
                refresh: true,
            }),
        ],
    });
```

I believe it'll be something to do with the fact that my homestead project is being served via ssl so, I tried to specify my .crt and .key files as per the docs found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener)

(https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener)

However, when I re-run vite (run as `npm run dev --host 0.0.0.0`), it still fails to load my JavaScript with connection refused.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing vite configuration

change `host: 'my-homestead-url.test',` to IP address

Here is my `vite.config.js` file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        hmr: {
            protocol: 'ws',
            https: false,
            host: '192.168.56.56',
        },
        host: "192.168.56.56",
        https: false,
        watch: {
          usePolling: true,
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

Then open your package.json file and add `--host` to the `"dev": "vite"` and it should be like `"dev": "vite --host"`

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "vite build"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `Homestead.yaml` is not configured correctly.
I see `app.js` file being requested on port 5174 but in your `Homestead.yaml` file you are redirecting 5173 port.

```yaml
ports:
     - send: 5173    # change these ports to 5174
       to: 5173
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate to ensuring the correct port is set and strict, if `ssl: true` is set in the `Homestead.yaml` config and a homestead site is using `https`, then mismatched/non-secure content warnings or errors might be displayed in the console if the vite server is not using `https`.

I would recommend copying the cert and key files for the site from the Homestead VM `/etc/ssl/certs/` directory into a shared folder such as `/home/vagrant/code/certs` owned by user:group `vagrant:vagrant` and then updating the `vite.config.js` config to use `https`. Also for Homestead, it is said you have to turn polling on for the vite server.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
import fs from 'node:fs';
import path from 'node:path';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: 'my-homestead-url.test',
        port: 5173,
        strictPort: true,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(`/home/vagrant/code/certs/my-homestead-url.test.key`),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(`/home/vagrant/code/certs/my-homestead-url.test.crt`),
            },
        hmr: {
            host: 'my-homestead-url.test',
        },
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                }
            }
        }),
        laravel({
            input: [
                // 'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```